# Динамическое выделение с помощью malloc

Tags: c++, c, malloc

```
int* f = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
*f++;
free(f);
```

Почему на функции free программа падает?

Comment: Потому что вы сдвинули указатель на 4 байта вперед, а `malloc`, не выделял память там. Вам стоило написать вот так `(*f)++;`

Comment: См. приоритеты операторов в C++.